# Created elements buttons in jQuery, but second element won't appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

My problem is that I am trying to dynamically create two buttons in jQuery, but I can never get the second button to appear the way I want it to--when I can get it to appear at all.

My goal is to use jQuery to add two buttons to a page. The page is an exercise I am doing to learn jQuery and Javascript. Due to the assignment, I am creating all elements in the body dynamically.

When I run the following code, the "Reset" button is created; the "Resize" button is not. The `#container` and the other `<div>`s are all generated without incident.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("<button id='reset'>Reset</button>").appendTo('body');
    $("<button id='resize'>Resize</button").after('#reset');

    var container = $('<div id="container"></div>');
    $(container).appendTo('body');

    for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        $('<div class="bricks"></div>').appendTo('#container');
    }

    $('.bricks').hover(function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
    });

});
```

I have specified CSS rules for the `#container` and the `.bricks` but not for any other elements. My original DOM contains only an empty `<body>` tag.

I originally tried to use `.appendTo('body')` for both buttons, which resulted in the first "Reset" button appearing as intended, with an empty button appearing after it where I had intended the "Resize" button to appear.

I have searched for related material extensively without results, so I hope this query is not redundant!

Comment: You're missing a closing carrot on the closing reset `button` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick check of the [`.after()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/after/) tells me that you need to reverse the syntax. From the docs : `With .after(), the content to be inserted comes from the method's argument: $(target).after(contentToBeInserted)`

Try this:

```
 $("#reset").after('<button id='resize'>Resize</button>');
```